# Limit the count and get the rest as "Others"

Tags: mysql, sql

I 'm counting a something for displaying in a piechart. I want to display only highest 6 counts by number with actual investmentType and the rest as "Others" as investmentType.

```
SELECT i.investment_type AS investmentType,
       COUNT(*) AS investmentCount 
  FROM investment i,
       vertical v 
 WHERE v.vertical_name = i.investment_type 
   AND v.type = 'STR' 
   AND i.status_funding = 'o' 
 GROUP 
    BY i.investment_type 
 ORDER 
    BY investmentCount desc
```

The above query gives me a result

[image]

By adding  `limit 6` to the query i get

[image]

What i need is one more row with investmentType "Others" and investmentCount "7".

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using ? MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite... ? There are some variations between all those systems. (you should also add it to the tags of your question)

Comment: MySQL.Sorry. will add that tag too.

Comment: @പുപ്പുലി .. Did you try sub queries??

Comment: What about a query where you skip the first six and put the name "Other" and for investmentCount you take the "SUM" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a try at something like:

```
    SELECT i.investment_type as investmentType,COUNT(*) as investmentCount FROM investment i,vertical v 
    WHERE v.vertical_name  =i.investment_type AND v.type='STR' AND i.status_funding ='o' 
    group by i.investment_type order by investmentCount desc
    limit 6
UNION
    SELECT "others" as investmentType, SUM(othersInvestmentCount) as investmentCount FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as othersInvestmentCount FROM investment i,vertical v 
        WHERE v.vertical_name  =i.investment_type AND v.type='STR' AND i.status_funding ='o' 
        group by i.investment_type order by investmentCount desc
        limit 6, 4294967296
    )
```

I did not test this query, you can edit it if you find syntax problems. Three actual queries involved, but it should not be crazy slow (and if faster is not needed, then no need to try faster).

I am assuming that you have less than 2^32 records in your database, which seems like a very reasonable assumption for a MySQL database (but just replace it by 2^64 if you feel insecure).